# Error connecting to sql server with docker, rbase, and RODBC

Tags: r, docker, rodbc

I'm trying to access a SQL Server on a local intranet with R, where R is loaded in a docker file with R-base.

On my desktop, I create a ODBC driver and it recognizes my windows credentials with the following:

```
odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=<serverName>;database=<dbName>;trusted_connection=yes')
```

Using R-base, after a lot of trial and error I was able to get RODBC installed, but I have no idea how to connect to this server.

```
Warning messages:
[RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found
```

The DockerFile, which was built with a lot of trial and error. I'm sure much of it is redundant. Also I exposed ports which I found doing some research but I have no idea if they are needed to be exposed.

```
FROM openanalytics/r-base

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libssl1.0.0 
# RODBC
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    unixodbc \
    unixodbc-dev \
    r-cran-rodbc \
    apt-transport-https \
    libssl-dev \
    libsasl2-dev \
    openssl \
    curl \
    unixodbc \
    gnupg \
    libc6 libc6-dev libc6-dbg

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
#RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev mssql-tools


EXPOSE 3838
EXPOSE 8787
```

Once I build the file, I enter R studio and use `install.packages("RODBC")`

How can I connect to the SQL server from the docker file?

----------Update

after creating a docker container with Ubuntu, I found that I was not able to ping the server name. I was however, able to ping the server ip address.

I modified the search string to ping the ip address, and changed the driver, as follows:

```
odbcDriverConnect('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};server=<serverName>;database=<dbName>;trusted_connection=yes')
```

This still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out how to connect to the database with the Windows credentials of the docker host inside of the docker virtual machine.

I had to make a username and password for the database and connect with that.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you change your driver to FreeTDS this will work. R doesn't support Sql Server drivers unless its a pro plan.